# UUID as a 32 ANSI hex character string

Tags: powershell

According to [this page](https://keepass.info/help/base/importexport.html#xml):

> The UUID is a hex-encoded 16-byte string (i.e. an 32 ANSI hex
>   character string in the XML file). It is unique (also across multiple
>   databases) and can be used to identify entries.

If I have say UUID `A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723`, how do I get to the equivalent 32 ANSI hex character string `vA2PMrJnmEmGZU9Lahgn5A==` using Powershell so that I can use it in a XML file?

Comment: What gave you the idea that "A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723" and "vA2PMrJnmEmGZU9Lahgn5A==" were equivalent in the first place?

Comment: I can create a manual entry in Keepass GUI and then export it to XML. I can view the UUID in the GUI as A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723 and see vA2PMrJnmEmGZU9Lahgn5A== in the XML file. 006B8FA4D68E487DA6D44FEF92731723 is AGuPpNaOSH2m1E/vknMXIw==

Comment: I suppose then you'll have to ask the author what kind of encoding they used for getting from one to the other. Because neither the GUID, nor the source string itself, nor a byte-sequence interpretation of the source string translate to that base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

I should point out that `A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723` *is a 32 ANSI hex chatacter string* already.

What you're asking for is a base64 encoding, which you can obtain from a GUID like so:

```
$guid = [guid]'A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723'
$bytes = $guid.ToByteArray()
[convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Comment: It "works" but the output of the above is AGuPpNaOSH2m1E/vknMXIw== When I look in the GUI of Keepass the UUID is displayed as 006B8FA4D68E487DA6D44FEF92731723, not A48F6B008ED67D48A6D44FEF92731723

Comment: Guess it is also A4 8F 6B 00 8E D6 7D 48 A6 D4 4F EF 92 73 17 23